# How can Brownian motion be a function of space only?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Typically, we see the notation $W(t)$ which represents an $\mathbb{R}^n$-dimensional Brownian motion (BM). What about $W(x)$? I've seen this in some papers where it is considered a space-dependent BM.

I don't understand how this can make sense. I know that $W(x,t)$ can be thought of as a separate BM at every point $x$. So perhaps $W(x)$ is a "slice" of $W(x,t)$ at a fixed time. Would this have the same properties as $W(t)$? If so, how can we interpret $W(x)$ without thinking of $x$ as a time variable? And if not, what would this thing be?

Comment: This isnt just some weird notation for the the value of the BM at $t=0$?

Comment: No, it's studied as a stochastic process

Comment: e.g. see https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0036142901387956?casa_token=A7nu54Q4c1sAAAAA%3AhUMvgk3t1xSS0o-LT_G5RDtgsTaVjPZQW5GYsjXIxfpRg884IeSlt0eauSHAiOBfdxgQCJVxA87C&journalCode=sjnaam section 2

Comment: Are there any systems modelled by the 'heat equation' where instead of a partial derivative with respect to t it is a partial derivative with respect to some other variable?

Comment: @Paul I don't think so, why? The $x$ in $W(x)$ is the same $x$ as in $u_{xx}$ of the heat equation

Comment: The t corresponds with the $u_t$ in the heat equation and it is that you want to replace isn't it?

Comment: The authors of the paper you linked seem to consider only $x \in [0,1]$ in the notation $W(x)$, so I believe it is the standard Wiener Process. However, there is a generalisation of $d-$ dimensional Brownian motion indexed by (time) $t \in \mathbb R_+$ to "Brownian sheet" indexed by $t \in \mathbb R_+^n$ and taking values in $\mathbb R^d$. This is a particular example of processes called Gaussian fields.

Comment: @Paul I don't want to replace the $t$, I want a $t$-independent equation. In the case of the heat equation, this would be $0=u_{xx}$.  So is the time-independent SDE just the stationary state of the heat equation?

Comment: @DominikKutek I've heard of Gaussian fields but don't know much about it. Is the time-independent Brownian motion simply a GRF?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about $W(t)$ and wondered if any meaning could be given to $W(x)$.